# Assign multiple numbers to one turtle in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, assign

For a course I'm following, I have to design some sort of AI that can navigate through a given 'terrain' which contains enemies (give damage), friends (lower the damage), obstacles (decrease energy) and stations (increase energy).

Before I proceed to the actual AI part, I want to have to the underlying point system in order. My question is; Is it possible to show 2 numbers at 1 turtle? I want to show damage as well as energy by the robot.

```
The energy part looks like the following:

to hit-station
   ask robots  
    [ if pcolor = green 
    [ set pcolor black set energy (energy + energy-from-station) ]
          ifelse show-energy?
          [ set label energy ]
          [ set label "" ]
]
end
```

Now this works perfectly fine since I made a switch for showing the energy. The problem arises when i want to add a number for the damage. I made a switch for this as well and the code part looks like the following:

```
    to hit-obstacle
      ask robots 
      [ if pcolor = red 
      [ set pcolor black set energy (energy + energy-from-obstacles) ] 
           ifelse show-damage?
           [ set label damage ]
           [ set label "" ]
]
end
```

I don't receive an error but the damage doesn't seem to show (the damage code part is beneath the energy code part).
Is this possible and is there a way to assign a different color to the numbers?

Thanks a lot in advance,

J.V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `turtles-own`, you can assign as many attributes to a turtle as you wish.  But a turtle can only have one value for its label.  You must decide what is to happen if you have a turtle that finds both a station and an obstacle.  You can show the energy, or show the damage, or show a label incorporating both.  In terms of your code above, note that you never set `damage` (only `energy`), so you are probably just seeing a `0` label when `damage` is reported.